# Should be a lambda expression-LISP

Tags: lambda, expression, lisp

Just one function of my code:

```
(defun equalprev (x y)
  (cond ((or (atom x) (atom y))
         (if (not (null isLoop))
             t
           ((setq list1 (append list1 (list x)))
            (setq list2 (append list2 (list y)))
            (eql x y))))
        ((equalprev (car x) (car y))
         (equalprev (cdr x) (cdr y)))))
```

```
*** - SYSTEM::%EXPAND-FORM: (SETQ LIST1 (APPEND LIST1 (LIST X))) should be a `lambda`
expression
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please [indent](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-style) things [properly](http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternate expression for the 'if' expression is ((set! ...) ...).  The first position needs to be either a function or a syntactic form.  In this case you need progn as:

```
(progn
  (setq list1 ...)
  (setq list2 ...)
  (eql x y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using de Morgan's laws you could construct your condition differently:

```
(not
 (when (null isLoop)
   (setq list1 (append list1 (list x)))
   (setq list2 (append list2 (list y)))
   (not (eql x y))))
```

avoiding the use of progn altogether (not that it's a bad thing, but it's often times frowned upon).